# C++ Polymorphism need assistance

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I had to take an inheritance between class person and class student and then write a test program using the polymorphic pointer pIndividual. The program compiles but it isn't listing student1 stats for me.

Here is my code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;

    class Person
    {
    public:
         string m_Name, m_Address, m_City, m_State;
         int m_Zip, m_Phone_Number;

         void virtual list_stats();
    };

     void Person::list_stats()
     {
           cout << "This is the function show_stats() that is in class Person to show   person1's " << endl;
          cout << "information:" << endl << endl;
          cout << "Name: " << m_Name << endl << "Address: " << m_Address << endl << "City: " << m_City << endl; 
          cout << "State: " << m_State << endl << "Zip: " << m_Zip << endl << "Phone Number: " << m_Phone_Number << endl << endl;
      }

      class Student : public Person
      {
      public:
            char m_Grade;
            string m_Course;
            float m_GPA;
            void virtual list_stats();

           Student(float GPA = 4.0);
      };

      Student::Student(float GPA)
      {
           m_GPA = GPA;
      }

      void Student::list_stats()
       {
          cout << "This is the function show_stats() that is in class Student to show student1's " << endl;
          cout << "information by using pointer pIndividual:" << endl << endl;
          cout << "Name: " << m_Name << endl << "Address: " << m_Address << endl << "City: " << m_City << endl; 
         cout << "State: " << m_State << endl << "Zip: " << m_Zip << endl << "Phone Number: " << m_Phone_Number << endl << endl;
   }

    int main()
      {
          Person person1;
          person1.m_Name = "Sarah";
          person1.m_Address = "ABC Blvd.";
          person1.m_City = "Sunnytown";
          person1.m_State = "FL";
          person1.m_Zip = 34555;
          person1.m_Phone_Number = 1234567;

          person1.list_stats();

          Student student1(4.0);
          student1.m_Name = "Todd";
          student1.m_Address = "123 Four Dr.";
          student1.m_City = "Anytown";
          student1.m_State = "TX";
          student1.m_Zip = 12345;
          student1.m_Phone_Number = 7654321;
          student1.m_Grade = 'A';
          student1.m_Course = "Programming";


          Person* pIndividual = new Student;
          pIndividual->list_stats();

          system("PAUSE");
          return EXIT_SUCCESS;
     }
```

Comment: That is an optimistic grading system where students start with a 4.0 GPA by default (do you really want to support that default? [no? => remove the default value] do you want to support implicit conversions from `float`? [no? => make the constructor `explicit`])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are creating *another* instance of `Student` with `new`. This default constructed instance does not have any data set. You need:

```
Person* pIndividual = &student1;
```

to get a pointer to the `student1` you created and to see its data when calling `list_stats()`.

Comment: You're welcome, glad it helped. Since you are new: Have you read about [accepting answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)?